# Fill a singleton once and access data from all threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, memory-visibility

I am on my cell phone now, so I have no code here. But it's simple.

I have one static class working as a singleton in a web app.
That class is called on the start of the application (when I use to fill my singleton passing a parameter after a database call). The problem is, that when I call that class again from a different static class (on a different thread), my data is not there. But if I use the same class which I used to fill, the data is there. **What can I do to access my singleton from all classes/threads and get the data?**

**UPDATE**
Hey guys, i solved it. The problem was that my system had two separated packages (linked by a rest service). My singleton was called by that two packages so i got different threads. The solution was create a method and get my singleton by the same package.

Comment: Without code it is difficult to guess but this sound like you either need to use the [volatile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4) modifier or use [Atomics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html).

Comment: Thanks buddy, I will take a look and update the code since I get home

Comment: It doesn't look like you have created a singleton. Please upload the code.